# ClassNotFoundException for Dependency in Velocity Minecraft Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, classnotfoundexception, maven-dependency

I'm currently developing a **Velocity Minecraft plugin**, and I'm encountering a **ClassNotFoundException** for FileUtils from org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils, even though I have added the library to my project's dependencies in the pom.xml file.

All compiles fine, but when I run the plugin on my velocity proxy server and execute the command, I get the **ClassNotFoundException**.

I'm using Velocity version 3.2.0-SNAPSHOT and Java 17 for my project. The dependency that causes the issue is org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils from commons-io version 2.13.0.

My Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pvpstartplugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>PvpStart</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>
            17
        </java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>papermc</id>
            <url>https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.velocitypowered</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is were I use **FileUtils**:

```
package pvpstartplugin.command;

import com.velocitypowered.api.command.SimpleCommand;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PvP implements SimpleCommand {

    @Override
    public void execute(Invocation invocation) {
        File sourceWorldDir = new File("/server/mc/castleGame/castleWorlds/Riveredgecastle/world");
        File targetWorldDir = new File("/server/mc/castleGame/pvpServer/world");

        try {
            copyWorldContents(sourceWorldDir, targetWorldDir);

            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("./start.sh");
            processBuilder.directory(new File("/server/mc/castleGame/pvpServer"));
            processBuilder.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void copyWorldContents(File source, File target) throws IOException {
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(target);
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, target);
    }
}
```

I also **tried version 2.11.0** of the library, but it did not work.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I have confirmed that the **commons-io-2.13.0.jar is present in my ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-io/2.13.0/** directory.

Any help is appreciated